# Google Calendar Notification not making any sound on iPhone 6

Tags: iphone, notifications, google-calendar

I am on iOS 12.1.2

I would like to use only ONE app for all my reminders and task management.

I think Google Calendar fits the bill nicely. Beautiful web-interface, pretty app, reminders, events etc.

However, there is one problem. Two actually.

1. I can't configure a sound for it like I can for Apples Calendar app.
2. Even if I allow sounds in Settings > Notifications on iPhone, and set notifications for events in the app itself. I get the notification alright, but no sound.

Ideally, I would like to hear a sound *and* be able to configure it.

Comment: is your sound on?

Comment: Yes it is. Yes it is.

Comment: Checkout https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/364857/402813 sync your Gmail calendar with Apple Calendar. You will be punctual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either turning your sound all the way up or actually turning on your ringer for your phone.

If that doesn't work, go into your settings and make sure that the ringers sound is all the way up and see if that works.