# Configure Google Calendar notification sound on iOS

Tags: notifications, google-calendar

On iPhone we can configure notification sounds for iCloud Calendar and the iPhone Reminders app, but I cannot find any way to configure a sound for Google Calendar app on iPhone. I find the default sound to be too meek.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Be reminder.**

There is no way to customise the notification sound for **3rd party applications** until the app developer build that functionality into their app. Applications like `WhatsApp` has options for that, you can change the notification sound from the app settings itself.

I suggest your can sync your account with `Calendars` and change `Calendars` notification sound.

Settings > Calendar > Accounts > Gmail(your account) > turn on sync Calendars

Comment: What does the heading "Be Reminder" mean?

Comment: @SaadRehmanShah Because, jaildbreak iOS exclude. If jaildbreak, can do customize.